# Error with Elasticsearch SSL keystore when trying to do remote reindex

Tags: elasticsearch, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm using Elasticsearch 8.1.4. I'm trying to perform a remote reindex and the remote ES has been configured with SSL by someone else. I was able to get the `abc.p12` cert of the remote ES, as well as the password that was auto-generated (an alpha-numeric string).

I'm not very familiar with the TLS/cert concept and I'm a bit confused as to what I should do.

I currently have the following configurations in my `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`.

```
reindex.remote.whitelist: ["x.x.x.x:9200"]
reindex.ssl.keystore.path: abc.p12

xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: false

xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: true

xpack.security.transport.ssl:
  enabled: true
  verification_mode: certificate
  keystore.path: certs/t.p12
  truststore.path: certs/t.p12
```

I'm taking this [page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/configuring-tls.html#node-certificates) as reference.

I overwrote the `xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.secure_password` and `xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.secure_password` with the one I have for `abc.p12`. However, I got the error message `failed to load SSL configuration [xpack.security.transport.ssl] - cannot read configured [PKCS12] keystore (as a truststore) [/etc/elasticsearch/certs/t.p12] - this is usually caused by an incorrect password; (a keystore password was provided)`.

If I don't overwrite the 2 passwords, then I get another error instead: `cannot read configured [PKCS12] keystore [/etc/elasticsearch/abc.p12] - this is usually caused by an incorrect password`

`t.p12` was used by the previous administrator to reindex from other remote ES. I'm not really sure if I need to provide my own `t.p12` (or what it is for, actually).

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this error and was following https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.7/security-basic-setup.html for reference. The error was because I did not enter a password "Create a password for the certificate and accept the default file name." While you can leave the password for the CA blank, I think may need to enter password for the certificate. Otherwise, I was also receiving this error ...this is usually caused by an incorrect password; (a keystore password was provided)

And then also need to do this part:
If you entered a password when creating the node certificate, run the following commands to store the password in the Elasticsearch keystore:

./bin/elasticsearch-keystore add xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.secure_password
./bin/elasticsearch-keystore add xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.secure_password